# Making a bot for impactjs-game

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, socket.io, bots, impactjs

I have a multiplayer 2d shooter game for 2 players made in impactjs and socketio, and I need to make a bot which will replace one of players and make basic actions like finding players, ammos, shooting and hiding if it has no ammos.

I decided to try implement it with Selenium webdriver, and I can pass coordinates of player position, second player position to webdriver, but I couldn’t find enough information about pathfinding algorithms with velocity and jumps, if it what is needed here. Any suggestions?